# finding value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DaqSamoaNtcac0ona-g3F6yM4euFC-CA/view?usp=sharing). I want to select value of a specific student. after that I want to apply condition of "if else" mean if CSC103 marks is grater than 70. print hi

```
df_xlsx =pd.read_excel('/content/FA15-BSE.xlsm' ,sheet_name = 'Final')
df = df_xlsx[df_xlsx['Registration#'] == FA15-BSE-081]
df
if df.CSC103 >= 70:
print('hi')
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't read image. Please provide a copy of your dataframe.

Comment: can i Share a link of google drive

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a standard `pandas` question, and has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: okay sir. I'll take care next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with the XLS provided.

```
import pandas as pd

df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('FA15-BSE.xls', sheet_name = 'Final')

# note the space after the Registration #
student_reg = 'FA15-BSE-001 '

# If you want to use like this:
# student_reg = 'FA15-BSE-001'

# You need to ignore leading or trailing spaces with .str.strip()
# student_data = df_xlsx[df_xlsx['Registration #'].str.strip() == student_reg]

student_data = df_xlsx[df_xlsx['Registration #'] == student_reg]

# student_data['CSC103 (4)'] returns a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# Do print(type(student_data['CSC103 (4)'])) and see for yourself
# So you can retrieve the item with [0] like in a list
# If need first matched value you can also use `iter` with `next`: 
# if next(iter(student_data['CSC103 (4)']), 0):
# advantage is if no value is matched is returned default value (0 in this case):
if student_data['CSC103 (4)'][0] >= 70:]
    print('Hi')
else:
    print('Need to study more')
```

Which Yields

```
hi
```

Comment: Then the issue is related to your xls.

Comment: bro it works but only on 001 reg. no. what will i do if I want reg no. 080. and what does [0] mean

Comment: hi bro I tried this. but it still gave an error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

please have a look to my code
def fyp_recy():
   a = df['Sr.#'] - 1
   a
   if df['CSC103 (4)'][a] >= 70:
     print('hi')
   else:
     print('your marks is less than 70')

Comment: Can you share your xls?  Don't forget to insert the sheetname. In my example I didn't used it. You have to know beforehand the Registration# as you put in your original code. That's why you are retrieving only one row.

Comment: it's the link. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yx2XtjC_Aswp12V-HiGdOqbwDLJG1Fd_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Osama Billah Solved. Take a look. The problem was with leading and trailing spaces in your XLS. Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote if it helped you.